# Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed

Tags: php, mysql, sql

He tenido un error en la creación de una FOREIGN KEY. Quisiera saber que estoy haciendo mal. Pues llevo bastante tiempo tratando de saber cual es el error. Gracias
Anexo codigo Sql:

```
CREATE DATABASE freatico;
USE freatico;
CREATE TABLE medicion (
    ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    IDP int(4) not null,
    Nivel float(5) not null, 
    Hora time not null, 
    Fecha date not null, 
    Persona text(40) not null,
    SMS varchar(70) not null,
    FOREIGN KEY(IDP) REFERENCES puntos(Id)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE puntos (
    Id int(4) PRIMARY KEY not null,
    Localizacion text(35) not null,
    UltiMed float(5) not null, 
    Vreferencia float(5) not null, 
    AlTubo float(5) not null, 
    SMS varchar(60) not null
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    ID int(4) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Nombre text(40) not null, 
    Correo varchar(50)not null,
    Username varchar(20) not null, 
    Password varchar(40) not null,
    Cargo text(50) not null
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas tratando de referenciar una tabla que no existe.  La solucion es crear primero la tabla `puntos` y despues la tabla `medicion`

Comment: Muchas gracias. Me funciono!. Oye otra pregunta para que casos se ultiliza CONSTRAINT? dentro de la instruccion o porque razon .Es que he visto codigos con esta etiqueta y no comprendo para que la utilizan .Gracias

Comment: Sirve para darle nombre a tus Constraints.  Si te funciono, marca la respuesta como correcta

Comment: Ya califique tu respuesta. Una ultima cosa cuando voy a Phpmyadmin a la opcion diseñador, no me aparecen relacionadas las dos tablas. ¿Sabes por que pasa?

Comment: Nunca he usado la opcion diseñador.  No uso phpmyadmin desde hace 4 meses.

Comment: jumm entiendo. Pero de acuerdo al código que viste, ¿las tablas ya quedaron correctamente relacionadas? o les hace falta algo?

Comment: Puedes probar ingresar un registro en la tabla medicion con un idp que no exista en la tabla puntos a ver si funciona o no